# How do you use a SoftLayer Object filter based on fullyQualifiedDomainName for virtual guests queries?

Tags: api, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am attempting to use the `REST API` to limit the result set of a `SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualServers` call. I want to use an object filter to limit based on the `fully qualified domain name`. I am passing the object filter like:

```
'{"virtualGuests":{"fullyQualifiedDomainName":{"operation":"cds-testprov-server-2.bluemix.net"}}}';
```

However, the filter is being ignored. If I try some of the other virtual guest values to filter on, like:

```
'{"virtualGuests":{"primaryBackendIpAddress":{"operation":"10.114.220.20"}}}'
'{"virtualGuests":{"id":{"operation":"10098133"}}}';
```

it works as expected. Is there something about the fullyQualifiedDomainName field that doesn't allow the use of the objectFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, you cannot apply a filter over "fullyQualifiedDomainName" I think is because the field is not stored in the database this is generated using the hostname and domain, so you should apply the filter over the hostname and the domain. You can use this filter:

```
{"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation": "oeg-search1"}, "domain":{"operation": "oeg.dal.slcommunity.org"}}}
```

Regards